# Ошибка при заполнении файла: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Tags: python, python-3.x

Итак, создаем .csv файл и заполняем первую строку таким образом

```
file = open('file.csv', 'wb')
writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter = ',')
columns = [str.encode('test_id'), str.encode('is_duplicate')]
writer.writerow(columns)
file.close()
```

Вылетает ошибка

> TypeError : a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Исключение вылетает в строчке **writer.writerow(columns)**

Comment: Если ошибка возникает прикладывайте стек трассы. Какой-то функции требуется bytes / bytearray объект, а не str

Comment: @gil9red str.encode() возвращает объект типа <class bytes>. И можете объяснить, что такое стек трассы

Comment: Когда происходит исключение, которое не ловит программист оно валит программу и в консоле пишется список функций и текст исключения, это и есть стек трассы, по нему понятно в какой функции произошла фигня )

Comment: @gil9red ошибка вызвана строчкой writer.writerow(columns)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для записи в csv файл, его нужно открывать для записи в текстовом режиме, а не в бинарном (режим открытия `'w'` или `'wt'`, а не `'wb'`). Тогда и кодировать вручную тестовые строки не нужно будет.

Рабочий пример:

```
import csv

file = open('file.csv', 'w')
writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter = ',')
columns = ['test_id', 'is_duplicate']
writer.writerow(columns)
file.close()
```